# Why "its" even though the noun is plural?

Tags: grammar

From [*Only Children Of The Universe Are We* by Dudley (CHRIS) Christian](http://books.google.com/books?id=5tHmAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA32&ots=sOPEYU5OEW&&pg=PA32&q=%22Let+the+young+have+its+youth%22#v=onepage), p.32:

> Let the young have **its** youth
>
> While you who have survived it look back in joy and
> appreciation or else in awe and wonder [...]

*Young* is plural so why is *its* used here?

Comment: Are you sure the previous sentence before "let the young ...", if any, has nothing to do with "its"?

Comment: @learner Google Books has page 30, which says "Let the young have **their** youth", and page 32, which says "Let the young have **its** youth".  Unfortunately, it doesn't have page 31, which might be necessary to make sense of the switch from *their* to *its* . . .

Comment: Could the young here means the generation of young? So you could address them with **them** as members and **its** as a whole? It's just a hasty thought, you would spare me further thinking if it was correct!

Comment: We have page 31, thanks to Damkerng! http://i.stack.imgur.com/o7BD1.png

Answer (score 1):

> Let the young have **its** youth
>
> While you who have survived it look back in joy and
>   appreciation or else in awe and wonder [...]
>
> > *Young* is plural so why is *its* used here?

George Bernard Shaw said "[Youth is wasted on the young.](http://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-say-youth-is-wasted-on-the-young)" This has become a famous quote among English speakers, and this phrase is used in the poem about halfway down on Page 31.

The author of the poem uses both *Let the youth have their young* and *Let the youth have its young* as a "refrain". The words of this refrain echo, or bring to mind, the quote by Shaw.

When the author switches from *their* to *its* to decribe *youth,* the first instance of

> Let the young have its youth

is followed by a lot of lines that contain *its:*

> Its aches and pains...
>   Its field of oats...
>   Its heartbreaking moments...

So I suspect it is a matter of style (*its* followed by a lot of other *its*). I have probably already crossed into literary interpretation, which is offtopic for ELL, but c'est la vie.

And yes, **the youth** can refer to **the generation of youth**, and

**The generation** is singular.

In the end, whether "Let the youth have its young" is grammatical or not is beside the point. It is how the author chooses to express himself. Self expression aint alway grammatical.

Note that I wouldn't exactly expect model grammar from someone whose book is called:

*Only Children Of The Universe Are We*

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it was wrong. 'The young' means 'young people'; it should be followed by the plural possessive.

Comment: **In general**, @username901345, animals have *offspring,* not *kids.* An exception is *goats,* whose offspring are called kids. Also, the word *teat* is used rather than *tit* when referring to animals.